# Not generating a valid password?

Tags: probability

### Generating a Valid Password (or Not)

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230676/56148) to the following question on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site:

- [password - How to generate a random string? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230673/how-to-generate-a-random-string)

suggests using commands like the following to generate a random string consisting of specific characters:

```
head /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' | head -c 32 && echo
```

The `|` and `&&` operators connect the individual commands. I'll explain a little bit more about the individual commands below.

It's possible that these commands will 'fail' and that the final output will be a random string shorter than expected (or required). We want, say, to generate a random string of (exactly) 32 (alphanumeric) characters, but it's possible the above commands will not do so. I suspect that this possibility is *very unlikely*, but how unlikely is it?

#### `head /dev/urandom`

The first command `head /dev/urandom`, reads the first 10 'lines' from [the pseudo-device */dev/urandom*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en//dev/random). For the purpose of this question, let's assume the following about the output of this command:

1. It's a a sequence of bytes, equivalent to a sequence of integers between 0 and 255 (including both)<sup>a</sup>.
2. At least 10 bytes are a 'newline', equivalent to the integer value 10.

Because the `head` command by default reads the first '10 lines' of its input, it must be in some sense reading bytes from the random device until it reads *11* newline character values, but whether the sequence itself output by the command includes the final eleventh newline character or not is irrelevant for answering this question (I think).

<sup>a</sup> I **was** *pretty* sure that the null byte, a byte equivalent to the integer value 0, terminates the `head` command, but given the sample data I collected, that seems unlikely. If a null byte does terminate `head`, it's possible that this command won't even read 10 lines. In that case too, the null byte, like the final eleventh newline character byte, shouldn't be considered part of the sequence output by this command. [I think this is reasonable.] But given that it *doesn't* seem like null bytes terminate `head`, I'm inclined to just treat them like any other possible character.

#### `tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9'`

This command filters the output of the previous command and returns a new sequence of bytes consisting only of those bytes that match the characters specified. In this case, only alphanumeric characters are returned.

For generating a password, typically we'd want to include 'special characters' and thus use a command more like the following:

```
tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()'
```

or even this:

```
tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'\''()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'
```

But, for the sake of answering this question, or at least for the sake of simplifying its initial analysis, feel free to consider only the first form of this command.

#### `head -c 32`

This command just reads and outputs the first 32 bytes/characters from its input (the output of the previous, second command).

#### `echo`

This command just prints a newline so that that the output of the other commands aren't immediately followed by the shell command prompt characters.

### The Question(s)

Given all of the assumptions above, what is the probability that these commands will *fail* to output a string of 32 characters?

In general, what is the probability that similar commands will fail to output a string of *n* characters?

What are the probabilities of similar commands failing to output a string of a certain length if we include additional 'valid' characters in our filter (the second `tr` command)?

### Some Empirical Evidence

I'm not sure where to start devising an analytical solution so I decided to test the commands directly.

I ran a script with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cases="${1:-1000}"

for (( i=0; i < $cases; i++ ))
do
    head /dev/urandom | dd 2>>~/all-bytes | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' | dd 2>>~/filtered-bytes > /dev/null
done
```

The `dd` commands output the number of bytes they receive in the command pipeline, the first being the number read by the first `head /dev/urandom` command, and the second being the number output by the `tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9'` command.

I ran `my-script 1000` (twice) and then `my-script 10000`. Here are histograms of the numbers of 'filtered bytes' for all of the commands run:

First 1,000 commands run:

[image: Histogram of first 1,000 commands run]

Second 1,000 commands run:

[image]

10,000 commands run:

[image]

Only one instance of running the commands – the first instance actually! – failed to generate a string of at least 32 characters. That it also generated *no* characters is somewhat suspicious. That result definitely seems to be an outlier. In every other run of the commands a minimum of 130 characters was output.

Based on this limited sample, the probability of failing to generate a valid password seems to be $~8.333 \times 10^{-5}$. I'm guessing the actual probability is significantly smaller.

Comment: I know this question is quite old, but there are 2 ways to attack this problem: 1) by fitting a distribution to lots of runs, as you did here, 2) having some theoretical mechanism for what causes the failure. What *would* cause such a failure?